# Setting up a Counter in a Table

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica, counter, nested-lists

I have two questions,

Q1.
The code is below:

```
orgtable = Table[{i, node2 = i + 1, node3 = node2 + 6, node4 = node3 - 1, 
                     node5 = i + 18, node6 = node5 + 1, node7 = node6 + 6, 
                     node8 = node7 - 1}, {i, 1, 36}
           ];
modtable = Drop[orgtable, {6, 36, 6}];
finaltable = With[{n = 5, m = 10},Flatten[Partition[modtable, n, n + m, 1, {}], 1]]
```

The first piece of code gives me an original table, the second one gives me a modified table, and the third yields the final table.
The output of the final table looks like this:

```
{{1, 2, 8, 7, 19, 20, 26, 25},    {2, 3, 9, 8, 20, 21, 27, 26}, 
 {3, 4, 10, 9, 21, 22, 28, 27},   {4, 5, 11, 10, 22, 23, 29, 28},
 {5, 6, 12,11, 23, 24, 30, 29},   {19, 20, 26, 25, 37, 38, 44,43},
 {20, 21, 27,26, 38, 39, 45, 44}, {21, 22, 28, 27, 39, 40, 46, 45},
 {22, 23, 29,28, 40,41, 47, 46},  {23, 24, 30, 29, 41, 42, 48, 47}}
```

But I want it to set up a counter to the final table so that my output should look like this(below):The counter will increase by 1 and in the below example it will start with 200;

```
{{200,1, 2, 8, 7, 19, 20, 26, 25}, {201,2, 3, 9, 8, 20, 21, 27, 26},
 {202,3, 4,10, 9, 21,22, 28, 27},  {203,4, 5, 11, 10, 22, 23, 29, 28},
 {204,5, 6, 12,11, 23, 24, 30, 29} and so on
```

As you can see from the desired output the count is present for each element and increases by one

Now question number two:

```
mycounter = 100;
tryone = 
   TableForm[
     Flatten[
       Table[{++mycounter, xcord, ycord, 
              (150*(Sin[((xcord - 90*2*3.14)/180]^2)*
                   (Sin[((ycord - 45)*2*3.14)/180]^2)
               ) + 20
             }, {xcord, 0, 200, 5}, {ycord, 0, 200, 5}
       ], 1
     ]
   ]
```

In the above example, I have successfully implemented a counter which is starting from 100 and incrementing by 1 and  it gives me an output

```
100 0 0 20.03

101 0 5 20.04 and so on..
```

But now I want to use the `Transpose` function on this, since I want to transpose the value presented but at the same time I don't want to transpose the "my counter".

```
mycounter = 100;
secondtry= 
  TableForm[
    Flatten[
      Transpose[
        Table[{++mycounter, xcord, ycord, 
                (150*(Sin[((xcord - 90)*2*3.14)/180]^2)* 
                     (Sin[((ycord - 45)*2*3.14)/180]^2)
                 ) +20}, {xcord, 0, 200, 5}, {ycord, 0, 200, 5}
        ]
      ], 1
    ]
  ]
```

But as you can see the Transpose function transposes also the "mycounter" which I do not want. **How do you prevent the transpose function from working on "mycounter" but work on the rest of it?**
Any other idea of implementing a counter in the above code is also welcome.

Comment: @Sjoerd ... You won the edit race :)

Comment: @belisarius Aren't we supposed to get an orange bar warning that we're editing simultaneously? Didn't see any.

Comment: @Sjoerd I did. But only when trying to save the edits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Removed answer to first question as I probably didn't understand what you wanted.*

As to the second question: I'm not sure whether I fully understand you here. If the counter belongs to the coordinate set the output should be left as it is, how awkward it may look. If the counter column is simply a line counter of the final output you could put in after you have done your flattening just like before.

But in this case, it seems the `Transpose` is fully superfluous. It suffices to switch the order of the indices of your table. If you do that you can leave your counter as it is:

```
mycounter = 100;
secondtry = 
  Flatten[
    Table[{mycounter++, xcord,ycord, 
          (150*(Sin[((xcord - 90)*2*3.14)/180]^2)*
               (Sin[((ycord - 45)*2*3.14)/180]^2)
          ) + 20}, 
          {ycord,0, 200, 5}, {xcord, 0, 200, 5} (* order switched here *)
    ], 1
  ]
```

A few notes: I removed the `TableForm` from your assignment. This is generally only used for printing and not for data that gets assigned to a variable. If you want to do an assignment and want to see the result at the same time you could try something like

```
 (myVar = Table[...{...},{...}] ) //TableForm
```

Also note that you don't have to multiply by 3.14/180 to convert degrees to radians. Mathematica has a built-in quantity named `Degree` for that (if you use the shortcut <kbd>esc</kbd> deg <kbd>esc</kbd> you will have a nice degree symbol instead). It looks like you are multiplying with 2 pi/180 for this conversion. If that was your intention, it was incorrect. The conversion is either 2 pi/360 or pi/180.  `((xcord - 90)*2*3.14)/180` should then be written as `(xcord - 90)Degree`.

Comment: Thanks a lot...you made me realize a major mistake

Answer (score 4):

Question 1 :

```
Transpose[Prepend[Transpose[#], Range[Length[#]] + 200]] &@
 {{1, 2, 8, 7, 19, 20, 26, 25}, {2, 3, 9, 8, 20, 21, 27, 26}, {3, 4, 
   10, 9, 21, 22, 28, 27}, {4, 5, 11, 10, 22, 23, 29, 28}, {5, 6, 12, 
   11, 23, 24, 30, 29}, {19, 20, 26, 25, 37, 38, 44, 43}, {20, 21, 27,
    26, 38, 39, 45, 44}, {21, 22, 28, 27, 39, 40, 46, 45}, {22, 23, 
   29, 28, 40, 41, 47, 46}, {23, 24, 30, 29, 41, 42, 48, 47}}
```

Question2:

```
Function[mat, 
  Partition[
   Transpose[Prepend[Transpose[#], Range[Length[#]] + 99]] &@
    Flatten[mat, 1], Length[mat]]]@
 Table[{xcord, 
   ycord, (150*(Sin[((xcord - 90)*2*3.14)/
          180]^2)*(Sin[((ycord - 45)*2*3.14)/180]^2)
     ) + 20
   }, {xcord, 0, 200, 50}, {ycord, 0, 200, 50}
  ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Create the rest of the table without the counter, create a suitable `n*1` matrix of the index using `Range`, and then use `MapThread` with the inner function `Join` to put the two together.

Answer (score 1):

Your `finaltable` could also be produced from `modtable` using `Table` as follows:

```
finaltableAlt = Delete[#, Transpose@{Flatten@Table[i + j, {i, 5, (
          Length[#] - 10), 15}, {j, 10}]}] & @ modtable
```

Another possibility for numbering:

```
MapIndexed[Flatten@{#2[[1]] + 199, #1} &, finaltableAlt]
```